# controlling the figure in the top left corner with powerdot

Tags: presentations, powerdot

I'm trying to change the width and the height of the figure appearing in the top left corner of a powerdot presentation with the default style. This is not achieved with the `logocmd` and `logopos` parameters of the `\pdsetup{}` command, is it ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is defined in the style files. You can change it with overwriting the definition. Here is the original one where you can change the height and/or width.

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\makeatletter
\pdifsetup{landscape}
{\sbox\pd@imagebox{\includegraphics[trim=50 20 0 20,clip,%
    width=.17\slidewidth,height=.1\slideheight]{powerdot-default.ps}}}
{\sbox\pd@imagebox{\includegraphics[trim=170 0 80 0,clip,%
    height=.1\slideheight]{powerdot-default.ps}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{foo}
bar
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

if you do not need a handout which is in portrait mode then you can simply use/redefine

```
\makeatletter
\sbox\pd@imagebox{\includegraphics[trim=50 20 0 20,clip,%
    width=.17\slidewidth,height=.1\slideheight]{powerdot-default.ps}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. Please, why do the file powerdot-default.ps appear two times in your first piece of code ?

Comment: the first definition is for the slides which are in landscape mode and the second for a handout which is in portrait mode.